# XCode 4.3.3 Appears to always run debug build version

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode 4.3.3 and have tried to configure my (one and only) scheme so that "Run" will build a release version (i.e. non-debug version) of my app for testing on the simulator and my device.

I attempt to do this as follows:

In the scheme editor window I highlight "Run" in the left column, and then for "Build Configuration" I select "Release". (I also set the debugger to "None").

However, when I build & run the application, the log navigator displays "Build MyApp1" followed by "Debug MyApp1".

My questions are: should this message displayed by the log navigator say "Release MyApp1" to reflect the build type I selected in the scheme editor?  Or does "Debug" in this message just always get displayed when you choose "Run"?  Is it in fact running the debug or release version?

Thanks,

BH

Answer (score 0):

Go TO Edit Scheme, choose the type that you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi & thanks for you reply but I have already done that step.   The scheme edit dialog is where I specified "Release" for the Running.  (In the screen shot you show, press the "info" tab to show this setting).  The logger still displays "Debug" when it runs.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that.  The scheme edit screen looks like the one you pasted above, and does allow me to select the Logging options.  The difference in my case, though, is that where yours says "Run Demo.app" with "Debug" underneath, mine says "Release" instead.  (BTW how do I paste images in my reply?)

Comment: @BitHead - For posting image you need to have certain reputation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test whether your compiled file is running a debug version, you can try something like this in your home controller's viewWillAppear:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
NSLog(@"running debug version");
#else
NSLog(@"running another version");
#endif
```

If you're not getting the result you're expecting, you can try setting the release flag to YES and debug flag to NO in build settings.

[image]

I hope this helps :-)